# How to add the effect of `button clicked`?

Tags: flutter

I created a custom button, how to add the effect of `the button clicked` as it happens for regular flutter button?

Or how to change the fill color of the button for small amount of time when the button clicked?

```
class KeyboardButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const KeyboardButton({required this.buttonChild});
  final Widget buttonChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: null,
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0).copyWith(bottom: 4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.white,
             ...
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Replace `GestureDetector` with `InkWell`.
- If you use null on `onTap`, the button will be disabled, so you can change it to `() {}` (no action will be done).

Comment: it's a custom button made with Container with decoration property where color of the button defined, so adding InkWell make no effect

Answer (score 0):

`InkWell` will be perfect for your need. You can customize the `clicked effect` color using `splashColor`.

```dart
class KeyboardButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const KeyboardButton({required this.buttonChild});
  final Widget buttonChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      splashColor: Colors.amber,
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0).copyWith(bottom: 4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.white,
             ...
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason doesn't work, splash property added